# Galaxy Note - UMTS 2100?

Tags: smartphone, samsung-mobile, cellular-network, umts

I'm buying a phone to take to Angola and I know that I should get one that has UMTS 2100 http://www.gsmarena.com/network-bands.php3?sCountry=ANGOLA

I'm interested in the Galaxy Note but I can't figure out if the GT-N7000 version is compatible. I've read a lot of spec sites and some seem to mention UMTS and some do not.  It probably doesn't help that I don't know the difference between UMTS and HSDPA.

So any info on whether the Galaxy Note GT-N7000 will work in Angola or an explanation of UMTS and HSDPA would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I guess you have already been to Angola, but anyway...If the phone is HSDPA capable, it will also be UMTS capable.

HSDPA = High Speed Downlink Packet Access.  Simple explanation is that it's an extra channel added into a UMTS system, for the purpose of downloading data faster.

Answer (score 0):

UMTS 2100 is a frequency band , which is a set of frequencies say 1900Mhz to 1950 Mhz ( there will be a different band for uplink ( your phone to the *nodeB* ( term for a mobile tower in UMTS ) which receives your signal ) and downlink ( nodeB to the phone ) ) which dictate at which frequencies your phone has to send and receives messages . So if Angola operates UMTS 2100 (usually a standard for most places ) your phone should also be able to operate at that band ( send and receive messages at that frequency ) .

If another new base stations is set up in the future in Angola  , even if it transmits signals at LTE bands if the phone does not support that frequency band you won't be able to use it . So it's advisable that UE ( user equipment ie phone, laptop) support all the frequencies possible so switching from gsm to UTMS or different carrier needs won't be an issue from the UE side

Looking at indian e-commerce site Flipkart selling the N7000 , over here        http://www.flipkart.com/samsung-galaxy-note-3/p/itme9978zcnnajza?pid=MOBDZQ2EZM3TAFBX&ref=L%3A-6277751913313120773&srno=p_4&query=note+3+&otracker=from-search

Scroll below to see Specificatons -> platform -> Operating freq

Here , it shows all the bands that can be supported by the phone . And yes , i do see UMTS 2100

So it does look like the standard international version definitely supports it . Only need to maybe be careful of certain european versions possibly , otherwise any standard e-commerce site should provide all necessary details
 like in this link in amazon   [http://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Galaxy-Unlocked-Android-Smartphone/dp/B00F33OE06/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1437240359&sr=8-1&keywords=note+3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00F33OE06)  its also clearly mentions the 2100 band

HSDPA is a protocol built on top of UMTS for higher data rates ( the *H* you see beside the signal bar on the phone ) so some sites mention only HSDPA for convenience , as they wouldn't like to mention UMTS + HSDPA possibly , so as the previous answer states if HSDPA 2100 is mentioned you are good to go .

If you are buying from a local dealer then make sure you cross check with shop owner or try to see in the sealed box if the operating frequencies are mentioned